# Vb.Net Move Mouse inside PictureBox

Tags: vb.net, mouseevent, mousemove

Hello i want  to move mouse to X,Y coordinates inside a Picture Box i am getting my coordinates from my Sub Like this

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    LocalMousePosition = PictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)

    txt_MouseLoc.Text = ("X=" & LocalMousePosition.X & "," & "Y= " & LocalMousePosition.Y)
End Sub
```

now let say x= 100 and Y = 100

i want to click a button and move mouse to ... you guessed it x100 y100

but i am using   this to move mouse

```
Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(x, y)
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
        Do_LMouseClick()
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
```

it moves the mouse to x100 and y100 according to screen and not picturebox1

i have tried

```
MouseLocation = picturebox1.pointtoscreen(x,y)
```

but no go  any ideas? thanks in advanced!

Comment: Yes!..That got it . now the mouse is moving a bit closer it is in the range, it is about few pxl off but definitely closer than before.

Comment: OK, sorry for deleting the comment by mistake... Hmm, the offset might be the windows title bar at the top

Comment: yeah.. also i have a MenuStrip... i have added +24 to compensate the Y and now it lines up! thank man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location needs to add the form's location and picturebox's location:

```
Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(x + Me.Location.X + PictureBox1.Location.X, _
                                          y + Me.Location.Y + PictureBox1.Location.Y)
```

---

UPDATE:

The form's title bar needs to be compensated by adding its height in the Y equation.